# Android: how create xml file that contains the list of albums and photos from gallery

Tags: android

Good morning,
i'm a newbie on Android development. I've learned recently how create a simple xml file using XmlSerializer. Here there is a part of what i have done.

```
serializer.startTag(null, "Albums");
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    serializer.startTag(null, "Album");
    serializer.attribute(null, "id", ""+i);
    for(int j=1; j<=10; j++){
        serializer.startTag(null, "photo");
        serializer.attribute(null, "id", ""+j);
        serializer.attribute(null, "name", "name"+j);
        serializer.attribute(null, "path", "path"+j);
        serializer.endTag(null, "photo");
     }
    serializer.endTag(null, "Album");
}
```

How you can see there is a simple "for" loop that creates a number of tags that i decide. 
My question regards how can i modify the code for have this kind of result:

```
for(int i=1; i<=totalNumberOfAlbumsInTheGallery; i++){
    serializer.startTag(null, "Album");
    serializer.attribute(null, "id", ""+i);
    for(int j=1; j<=totalNumberOfPhotoInTheCurrentAlbum; j++){
        serializer.startTag(null, "photo");
    serializer.attribute(null, "id", ""+j);
    serializer.attribute(null, "name", name_Of_The_Photo);
    serializer.attribute(null, "path", current_photo_Path);
    serializer.endTag(null, "photo");
    }
    serializer.endTag(null, "Album");
}
```

So in fact i don't know how find the number of the photo albums in the gallery. And i don't know how find the number of photos inside each album.
Can somebody help me please?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I am asking because considering the information you store it seems to me that it would be better to use a database. With a database it would be easy to find the number of photos, albums, to search certain photos, etc. For more information, please read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: I don't have to store informations using a database, i have only to find the number of photo albums and the number of the photo inside each album that are already presents on the device. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to get some basic java experience as these problems are really common in the programming world and has almost nothing to do with Android. Anyway you should make a List that holds Album objects (model) and an Album object should contain a List that holds Photo objects (model). Then you can loop though the list by getting the number of photos/albums with the List.size() method. Good luck.